# Notification center documentation for applescript

Tags: mac, applescript, script, notifications

Where can I find documentation for notification center method and properties to use it in applescript? I can't find anything in script editor's dictionary neither on web.

This is example code to work with notification center:

```
on run
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Notification Center"
           set theseWindows to every window
           display notification (count of theseWindows)
        end tell
   end tell
end run
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Great effort showing your code and asking a useful question. I'm going to edit the answer - they ask a very good question about what line 4 is expected to do. My edit to their answer will help explain counting a string, but not windows.

Comment: Note that `display notification` is a part of **StandardAdditions** and as such it does not belong within a `tell` _block_ of `process "Notification Center"` or `application "System Events"` and should be placed after the `end tell` of the `tell application "System Events"` _block_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Script Editor app has a searchable library. Open that under the window menu and then select the Standard Additions bundle. If you search for the term notification, you'll see it's defined under User Interaction:

```
display notification [text] : the body text of the notification
  [with title text] : the title of the notification (default is the name of the calling application).
  [subtitle text] : the subtitle of the notification
  [sound name text] : the name of the sound to play
```

But Notifications Center doesn't have any windows. Are you trying to count all windows for all applications?

To be clear - here's the notification part setting aside what a window count might be:

```
on run
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Notification Center"
            set theseWindows to "a b c"
            display notification (count of theseWindows)
        end tell
    end tell
end run
```

Comment: Note that `display notification` is a part of **StandardAdditions** and as such it does not belong within a `tell` _block_ of `process "Notification Center"` or `application "System Events"` and should be placed after the `end tell` of the `tell application "System Events"` _block_.